# iOS 11 stop default behaviour of swipe UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

In my App, one screen has table view and displaying **"Edit"** and **"Delete"** buttons on swipe `UITableViewCell`.

All is working good but issue is in default animation of `UITableViewCell` in iOS 11.

I know some behaviour and funda are changed in iOS 11.  When you are continue pulling to swipe your cell then `editActionsForRowAt` method will be called **automatically.**

Some times it's good but when you added more then one button on table swipe then looking ugly behaviour.

Look at below, Default behaviour of swipe cell in iOS 10 and iOS 11.

**iOS 10:**

[image]

**iOS 11:**

[image]

You can see in `iOS 11` if I pull to swipe then automatically `editActionsForRowAt` method os call and display alert message.

My question: Is there any why to stop this behaviour of iOS 11 and code for that?

Because if your table has more then 2 button then it's looking ugly.

Comment: why would you stop that? it is standard behaviour on iOS11, the end users will get use to it, if they have not got already.

Comment: @holex - Yes I accepting its standard behaviour but you can look at my last video. When table has more then one button and going to swipe then looking ugly end-user will confuse without do any action hows it happen.

Comment: that is an opinion based-assumption from you, so here is my opinion then: I'm an end-user too _(apart from being a dev)_ and I could not find that behaviour confusing at all; clearly something new, but definitely neither confusing nor ugly :)

Comment: however, here is the __hint__ from Apple Docs: it is worth to take a look on the [`UISwipeActionsConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipeactionsconfiguration) and `performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe` property as a start for instance.

Comment: As per my testing when I just swipe more then automatically my alert display that's why I'm asking nothing else  :)

Comment: @holex I'm not saying like this is fault of Apple, obviously Its attractive  and nice features. But in my case if you will take more then 1-2 button on swipe and on click of any button **alert** will display Same thing in iOS 11 it's looking little bit confusion without pass action/click  **alert** is displaying on the pull to swipe. I just want to stop this only for me. Cheer :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to do what you are looking for. However the animation isn't exactly the same as in iOS 10 but it eliminates the full swipe, and still looks good.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: UIContextualAction.Style.destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, view, completion) in
        //TODO: Delete
        completion(true)
    })

    let editAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: UIContextualAction.Style.normal, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, view, completion) in
        //TODO: Edit
        completion(true)
    })

    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])

    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
}
```

The key line is `config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false` as this will disable the full swipe.

The above code will override `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` on iOS 11 but your `editActionsforRowAt` will still be used for sub iOS 10 devices.

Comment: Let me check it, Thanks for your reply

Comment: i am used "editActionsForRowAt" method to add the left swipe in tableview cell please how to all the stop the full swipe inside of this method. because i am used supper the device for below the iOS 10.0 also.?

Comment: what line of code "completionHandler(true)" do in this situation?